# Django retornando hora errada no template, por quê?

Tags: python, django, timezone

Eu salvei no meu banco uma data, em um campo do tipo `datetime(6)`, a data salva no banco de dados é: `2020-05-13 14:13:50.000000`, porém, quando tento imprimir essa data no template utilizando `{{ user.time_vip }}` eu tenho como retorno `13 de Maio de 2020 às 11:13`, repare que a hora não bate com a hora que está salva no banco de dados.

Por que isso está acontecendo?

O meu `settings.py` está configurado assim:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Aproveitando, como eu poderia verificar se essa data (tempo) é maior que o dia de hoje?
Exemplo:

```
{% if user.time_vip >= timezone.now %}
<span class="d-block mb-3 mt-3 small text-success">Você é vip até {{ user.time_vip }}</span>
{% else %}
<span class="d-block mb-3 mt-3 small text-danger">Você não é vip</span>
{% endif %}
```

Este foi um exemplo, não funciona porque ele me retorna uma string como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A documentação explica essa definição:

## Internationalization

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

Para mostrar a data e hora da América do sul é só editar o `settings.py`:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Cuiaba' 

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
```

Comment: Só mantive `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'` e tornei `USE_TZ = False`, obrigado.